# Django NoReverseMatch when Debug=False

Tags: django

My django site works fine, but when I set the `DEBUG=False` it sends an email to me with the following error:

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'django.views.static.serve' with arguments
>   '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

I set `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']` and it did not solved.

The admin website works fine.

Any idea?

**EDIT**:

After some digging I found this error too:

> ```
> File "/srv/mysite/myapp/views.py", line 38, in home
>     { 'request': request}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
> ```

this is on my home view:

```
def home(request):

    return render_to_response('index.html', { 'request': request}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: See the [deployment section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/#deployment) in the static files documentation.

Comment: my statics are working fine....

Comment: Do you have STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/example.com/static/" in your settings.py

Comment: Can you please provide full traceback?

Comment: Ok, now it appear to be clear.... Burhan was right... there is something wrong with the statics: django.views.static.serve.... I will provide the files, just a min please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of adding `static.serve` for static files is generaly wrong. All you do is:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

so you'r files are accessible from `http://server_addr/static/` and in `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in templates

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project_dir', 'static'),
)
```

this generates ex. '/home/mcabra/dev/project/project_dir/static/' - my development statics are here

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static')
```

this is for production `manage.py collectstatic` copies modified files from `STATICFILES_DIRS` to `STATIC_ROOT` (so it's ready for ex. minification).

Then you use web server like Nginx for serving static files from `STATIC_ROOT`. Django defult WSGI web server is only for development purposes. see: Django Gunicorn.

Hope I helped.

**EDIT:**
from (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)
"Serving the files
In addition to these configuration steps, you’ll also need to actually serve the static files.

During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will be done automatically by runserver when **DEBUG is set to True** (see django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve())."

Answer (score 0):

You all were right, and I had a problem with the static files.

I just added this code on urls.py and it served the files.

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Tks